# How to use a PHP heredoc as an array value?

Tags: php, heredoc

I've a larger piece of multi-line text that I need to put in an PHP associative array through a here-doc. It looks like this:

```php
    $data = [
      "x" => "y",
      "foo" => "bar",
      /* ... other values ... */
      "idx" => <<< EOC
data data data data
data data data data
data data data data
EOC;
      "z" => 9,
      /* ... more values ... */
    ];
```

I can't figure out how to provide `$data["idx"]` the multi-line text with a heredoc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't end it with a semicolon at the end of the heredoc identifier. In PHP 7.2 and earlier the comma needs to be on a new line. It has to look like this:

```php
$data = [
  "x" => "y",
  "foo" => "bar",
  /* ... other values ... */
  "idx" => <<<EOC
data data data data
data data data data
data data data data
EOC
 , "z" => 9,
 /* ... more values ... */
];
```

Comment: Using `[ "x" => "y"]` instead of `array("x" => "y")` seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 9):

With PHP 7.3 things have [improved significantly](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/flexible_heredoc_nowdoc_syntaxes). You can now indent heredoc blocks:

```php
$data = [
  "x" => "y",
  "foo" => "bar",
  /* ... other values ... */
  "idx" => <<<EOC
    data data data data
    data data data data
    data data data data
    EOC,
  "z" => 9,
  /* ... more values ... */
];
```